# How to force reload and clear cache in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, caching, refresh, reload

it recently came to my attention that simply using `window.location.reload()` is not a hard refresh i.e. cache is cleared along with the refresh. I was then told to use `window.location.reload(true)` but I discovered this has since been deprecated.

I am not sure how to determine whether or not the cache has been cleared, so I feel that any method that refreshes the page simply won't cut it for what I need to do, as I cannot tell if cache is being cleared.

I have seen various other approaches including `window.location.href = window.location.href;` but have seen comments saying this does not clear cache.

I have seen people say that using a "POST" method should do the trick, but I am not sure how to implement this into my current code. I am using a `MatSnackBar` to prompt the user to refresh the page when a newer version of the app has been released. Here is the code for that SnackBar:

```
showSnackbar(versionFromHTTP: string, appVersion: string): void {
   const httpList = versionFromHTTP.split('.');
   const appList = appVersion.split('.');
   if ((httpList[0] === appList[0]) && (httpList[1] === appList[1])){
     let snack = this.snackBar.open('We\'ve made new updates! Please refresh your browser to get the latest updates.', 'Refresh now');
     snack.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
   }
   else{
     let snack = this.snackBar.open('We\'ve made new updates - some features may not work correctly until you refresh your browser.', 'Refresh now');
     snack.onAction().subscribe(() => {
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
    });
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the dependency on cache? when you build your Angular app, aren't you hashing the generated bundles?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela Hi, thanks for the comment. I have recently started a new job as a developer at a new company, as I just finished university. So I didn't build this app myself, but am now working on it, so I do not understand everything about the app I am afraid. But my boss says that the cache not being cleared may result in the snackbar not disappearing after the refresh.

Comment: Is your problem that snackbar is always visible on refresh?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela not always, but it can happen